# Exporting labels to Excel from a project

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I have a small problem - I have to list all the labels of several large shared projects, so labels that are missing a translation are identified updated.

Now what I'm looking is something like Palle Agermark's label export job (http://www.agermark.com/2011/10/export-and-import-labels-for.html) but one that goes through one or more projects and pulls all the label IDs (regardless of label series) and values for three languages to Excel.

Can this be done, any pointers? :)

Comment: What do you mean in large shared projects?  Do you mean all of the labels used on any element property inside of a project and anywhere in code where a label is used in side of that project?  Or are there actual label files stored inside of the project that you're interested in?  Do you know that you can right click and export the label file and it's just plain-text?  Are you trying to solve this with code for fun, or do you really just want to find missing translations, or are there so many label files themselves?  If it's missing translations, you could probably just open and spot-check.

Comment: "Do you mean all of the labels used on any element property inside of a project and anywhere in code where a label is used in side of that project?"

This. The projects have dozens, or over a hundred different objects. Going through everything by hand and copying them into Excel would take a frack-ton of time and sanity. And this is not for fun, in any meaning of the word :)

Comment: I wonder if you could export the projects to xpo files and simply _grep_ the relevant data out of them.

Comment: That would require someone to manually pull the translations from the label files/label editor and put all that into Excel.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: https://imgur.com/2Xn8e0k

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expands the idea of Jan B. Kjeldsen's last comment to get the labels from the project xpo file. The labels are saved in the xpo file in the following XML structure:

```
<Table:Record name="TmpSysLabel" xmlns:Table='urn:www.microsoft.com/Formats/Table'>
    <Table:Field name="Language">de</Table:Field>
    <Table:Field name="Label">Geplante Produktionsaufträge</Table:Field>
    <Table:Field name="Description"></Table:Field>
    <Table:Field name="LabelId">@SYS119128</Table:Field>
    <Table:Field name="SysLabelApplModule">0</Table:Field>
    <Table:Field name="recVersion">0</Table:Field>
    <Table:Field name="Partition">5637144576</Table:Field>
</Table:Record>
```

My first idea was to import this XML to Excel, but Excel does not play nice with column names in attributes. So instead I wrote an xsl that transforms the XML into something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<labels>
    <record>
        <Language>de</Language>
        <Label>Geplante Produktionsaufträge</Label>
        <Description />
        <LabelId>@SYS119128</LabelId>
        <SysLabelApplModule>0</SysLabelApplModule>
        <recVersion>0</recVersion>
        <Partition>5637144576</Partition>
    </record>
</labels>
```

To do this transformation, the original XML has to be cleaned up a bit, replace all occurences of `Table:Record` with `record` and all occurences of `Table:Field` with `field`. Also add a root XML node `labels`. It should look like

```
<labels>
    <record>
        <field name="Language">de</field>
        <field name="Label">Geplante Produktionsaufträge</field>
        <field name="Description"></field>
        <field name="LabelId">@SYS119128</field>
        <field name="SysLabelApplModule">0</field>
        <field name="recVersion">0</field>
        <field name="Partition">5637144576</field>
    </record>
</labels>
```

Now for the fun part (at least for me because I had not much prior knowledge of xsl syntax), the xsl transformation file. I ended up with the following, which will produce the wanted XML using http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <labels>
    <xsl:for-each select="Labels/*">
        <record>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:element name="{@name}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </record>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </labels>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The resulting XML can then be imported into Excel using the Excel developer Tools for XML. The result will look like [image: XML Labels in Excel]

Comment: Nice! Thanks, I think this'll do it :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to go to the label source directly.

In AX 2009 the labels are stored in the application folder and named like like axSYSen-us.ald with the following parts:

1. ax - the file prefix
2. SYS - the label name, @SYS123 labels are stored there
3. en-us - the language specifier
4. ald - the label file extension

The files are in text format and can easily be imported to Excel or edited with an text editor.

You could import to Excel, one sheet for each label file, then combine the output in a separate sheet (in the same workbook) using Excel formulas.

In AX 2012 the labels are stored in the model database and the .ald files are created on startup.

Comment: Yes, but this would not give me just the labels that are used in certain projects.

Comment: Then export the project and use the output in the XPO file. It will require more cleaning of input before it can be used, but the label part of XPO is in XML format; it should be easy to convert to tab separated or similar format.

Comment: Also, you can use SysLabel API to access labels: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg952024.aspx. Again scanning the XPO output would be the fastest way for a per project list of labels.