# How to get all labels used in a Report design?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, report, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm beginner for the report.

```
=Labels!@SYS7407 // I need to get this
```

I want to get all labels used in Expression Design report.

I need to export all Labels used [image: here]

It's possible to extract in a CSV file, with a JOB?
Or, if exist a functionally in Visual Studio to get all labels in my report.

Thansk all,

enjoy!

Comment: Try [Exporting labels to Excel from a project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524317/exporting-labels-to-excel-from-a-project/33551194#33551194)

Comment: @FH-Inway your response would probably be better as an answer, seems pretty good.

Comment: @AlexKwitny: Thanks. Actually I flagged this question as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers, where I have to put the XML code in Visual Studio ?

Comment: @FH-Inway I need to extract all label used in Expression report design.

Comment: @AlexKwitny , It's the same question than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524317/exporting-labels-to-excel-from-a-project/33551194#33551194 ?
Very thanks!

Comment: @ulisses: The answer I linked does not suggest that you have to put XML code in Visual Studio. Instead you should export the SSRS report object in the AOT (which also contains the label ids that you added in the Visual Studio designer) into an .xpo file and go from there.